# How to install --no-cache-dir tensorflow on amazon linux2 for ec2 instance for a flask application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, out-of-memory, requirements.txt

Whenever I have tensorflow in my requirements.txt and deploy flask application using amazon portal for ec2, it fails because installing tensorflow leads to "**MEMORY ERROR**". I have tried using the command manually using the virtual environment using --no-cache-dir and that works. The main error right now is, I do not know how to add the option --no-cache-dir in the requirements.txt, i have tried several different methods but i dont know how to place this option in the requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the EC2 instance you are using. There is a possibility that the instance is too small.

Another option is to use a tensorflow base image:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.3-gpu-py3
```

If you want more help, you should provide more details, such as your setup and scripts.